# How can I send an embed via my Discord bot, with python?

Tags: python, syntax, discord, bots

I've been working a new Discord bot. I've learnt a some stuff already and now I'd like to make the things a little more custom.

I've been trying to make the bot send embeds, instead of a common messages:

```
@bot.command()
async def testinfo(ctx, *, arg):
            idtouser = robloxpy.GetName(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            usergroups = robloxpy.GetUserGroups(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userjoin = robloxpy.AccountAgeDays(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userbanned = robloxpy.IsBanned(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userval = robloxpy.GetUserLimitedValue(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            onfriends = robloxpy.GetOnlineFriends(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            frinedsoff = robloxpy.GetOfflineFriends(f'{arg}'.format(arg))

embedVar = discord.Embed(title='user: {idtouser} account stats can be folow below'.format(arg))
embedVar.add_field(name = 'User value', value= "{userval}", inline = True)
embedVar.add_field(name = 'Check if banned', value = "{userbanned}", inline = True)
embedVar.add_field(name = 'User join date (in days)', value = "{userjoin}", inline = True)

embedVar.add_field(name = 'User groups', value = "{usergroups}", inline = True)
embedVar.add_field(name = 'Users friends online', value = "{onfriends}", inline = True)
embedVar.add_field(name = 'Users offline friends', value = "{friendsoff}", inline = True)

embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

When I try to run my bot I get that syntax error:

```
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation matters in Python, and is used to group blocks of code together. If we use your `testinfo` function as an example, all it contains is this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def testinfo(ctx, *, arg):
            idtouser = robloxpy.GetName(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            usergroups = robloxpy.GetUserGroups(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userjoin = robloxpy.AccountAgeDays(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userbanned = robloxpy.IsBanned(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userval = robloxpy.GetUserLimitedValue(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            onfriends = robloxpy.GetOnlineFriends(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            frinedsoff = robloxpy.GetOfflineFriends(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
```

The lines after this are not considered part of the `testinfo` function because they are not indented the same way. You can fix the syntax error by indenting the rest of the code to look like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def testinfo(ctx, *, arg):
            idtouser = robloxpy.GetName(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            usergroups = robloxpy.GetUserGroups(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userjoin = robloxpy.AccountAgeDays(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userbanned = robloxpy.IsBanned(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            userval = robloxpy.GetUserLimitedValue(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            onfriends = robloxpy.GetOnlineFriends(f'{arg}'.format(arg))
            frinedsoff = robloxpy.GetOfflineFriends(f'{arg}'.format(arg))

            embedVar = discord.Embed(title='user: {idtouser} account stats can be folow below'.format(arg))
            embedVar.add_field(name = 'User value', value= "{userval}", inline = True)
            embedVar.add_field(name = 'Check if banned', value = "{userbanned}", inline = True)
            embedVar.add_field(name = 'User join date (in days)', value = "{userjoin}", inline = True)

            embedVar.add_field(name = 'User groups', value = "{usergroups}", inline = True)
            embedVar.add_field(name = 'Users friends online', value = "{onfriends}", inline = True)
            embedVar.add_field(name = 'Users offline friends', value = "{friendsoff}", inline = True)

            embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```